# Xubuntu not recognizing printer

Tags: printing

Xubuntu doesn't seem to be allowing me to print from my printer. When I try to print files I can only print to a file. However, Ubuntu allows me to use the printer.
lsusb (on Xubuntu box) returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 03f0:2404 Hewlett-Packard Deskjet F2280 series
```

Comment: The output for `lsusb` shows that the printer *is* recognized. Why can't you print

Comment: @Lucio when I go to print a document, it doesn't show up in the list of printers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install HPLIP from Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center and after doing so you have to enter System Tools --> Printers, there you have to enable your printer and set it as default.

Comment: hplip is already the newest version.

Comment: Did you set the printer as *default* on the menu?